# I accidentally delete directory .npm in my(usr/) home, how do I do

Tags: node.js, npm, webserver

I accidentally delete the "invisible" directory ".npm" in my home directory (even include package.json) on my ubuntu webserver

And I still got an Node.js website running
(it's under /var/www/)

So how do I do to check my npm's status or how do I rebuild it?

Now my site seems working fine but I am so afraid that it will die after I restart something else...

Thanks for your help in advance, and sorry for my stupidity...

Down below is some feedback that npm gave me

```
root@localhost:/home/alex# npm restart
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-112-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "restart"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /home/alex/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/alex/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/alex/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/alex/npm-debug.log
root@localhost:/home/alex# npm install
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/alex/package.json'
npm WARN alex No description
npm WARN alex No repository field.
npm WARN alex No README data
npm WARN alex No license field.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.npm` directory is a cache so deleting it shouldn't affect anything running on your system.

The missing `package.json` file is a bigger deal potentially, but I suspect you are simply in the wrong directory. One typically doesn't have a `package.json` at the root level of their home directory (in your case, `/home/alex`). If I'm right about that, then the answer is to find out where the real `package.json` is.

If on the other hand, it really was in your home directory, and you don't have a backup of your home directory, then you'll need to regenerate it however you managed to create it in the first place. (And while you're at it, create a backup system so you're not in this situation again!)

I also see you are running Node.js 8.x. That version of Node.js was last supported in 2019. You are running a version of Node.js with known TLS/SSL vulnerabilities. Update to 12.x at least, and preferably 14.x.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you, understood clearly! And thanks for your suggestion!